# Why does dbClearResult() take so long?

Tags: r

I am baffled why a simple query takes so long when executed through MySQLConnect() 
I have a MySQL database ncol = 25 and nrow = 10000 is a samll databases,I would like to use MySQLConnect() get some dataframe ,but it's always take a lot of time

```r
      dbClearResult(dbSendQuery)  #take long time but why
      dbDisconnect(DBConnect)   #take long time but why
```

I checked Intelnet ,it's okey ,i use SequelPro for sure it was fast.

this is full code:

```
library("DBI")
library("RMySQL")
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")

    MySQLConnect <- function(N=1000) {
      DBConnect <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                user = "root",
                password = "root",
                dbname = "root",
                host = "root",
                port = 3306,
                )
      dbSendQuery <- dbSendQuery(DBConnect, "SELECT * FROM TABLE")
      dbFetch <- dbFetch(dbSendQuery, n=N)
      data.table <- data.table(dbFetch)
      dbClearResult(dbSendQuery)
      dbDisconnect(DBConnect)
      return(data.table)
      }

#platform       x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0   
#arch           x86_64                      
#os             darwin15.6.0                
#system         x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#status                                     
#major          3                           
#minor          6.1                         
#year           2019                        
#month          07                          
#day            05                          
#svn rev        76782                       
#language       R                           
#version.string R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#nickname       Action of the Toes
```

if i was send this, can be disconnect in immediately

```sql
SHOW PROCESSLIST FOR SEARCH "SELECT * FROM TABLE" ID;
KILL THIS ID;
"Closing open result sets"
```

how can i do this code for best?

---

Reason

```
  dbSendQuery <- dbSendQuery(DBConnect, "SELECT * FROM TABLE") #it's not run end over so dbClearResult(dbSendQuery) and dbDisconnect(DBConnect) is waiting
```

Comment: `but it's always take a lot of time` ... how much time is this script actually taking, and why are you surprised by it?

Comment: maybe 10 minutes or more , i use ```SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT 1000``` for 1-2 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues here. By using `n` in `dbfetch` you are actually running the full select statement then just pulling back the first n rows. I would try pasting N in as part of the SQL and then using `dbGetQuery` as it takes out 2 steps of your code and is probably faster.

Also don't save your result as a variable called `data.table` becasue it is already a function. Here you go:

```
MySQLConnect <- function(N=1000) {
  DBConnect <- dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
            user = "root",
            password = "root",
            dbname = "root",
            host = "root",
            port = 3306,
            )

  out <- dbGetQuery(DBConnect, paste0("SELECT * FROM TABLE LIMIT ", N))

  dbDisconnect(DBConnect)

  return(out)

  }
```

Comment: no problem, if so please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Very often, it is forgotten that R by default tries to load the whole data frame into the computer's memory, which is a big problem for large tables.

In your examples, you expect linearity in time (1k records : 1-2 seconds :: 10k records : 10-20 seconds), however you may not be taking into account that 10k records may not fit in your computer's available physical memory.

That's when memory swap comes in, usually wrecking havoc.

Usually, it feels like your computer is freezing, even with little to no processing at all (looking through `htop` linux command's glasses, for instance), because memory swap is rarely signalled by the OS.

So, it is possible that your table is already in your computer (i.e., in the connection layers below R itself) and the bottleneck occurs the minute R tries to choke the memory full of data, when also it starts slowing everything: receiving more data from your server, reacting to your interaction with mouse and keyboard.  For this reason, you can log in to your SQL server's monitor and kill the query right away, because it does not depend on R listening to you for, then, responding.

If you are curious enough, you can try using `microbenchmark` package to make a response curve for processing time in function of batch size to discover when the linearity breaks downs.

Available solutions:

- download the full table locally and work it locally

  - parallelize the processing if you want
  - using large data set packages: `bigmemory`, `data.table`
- discover your bootleneck batch size and work accordingly with batch sizes that big

  - `dbFetch()`ing blocks that large and processing them

Answer (score 0):

final code

```r
GetPlayerBroadInfo <- function(LIMIT = NULL) {
  dbConnect <- DBI::dbConnect(
    RMySQL::MySQL(),
    host = "root,
    dbname = "root",
    user = "root",
    password = "rootroot",
    port = 3306,
    ":memory:"
  )
  dbQuery <- "
    SELECT * FROM TABLENAME
    "
  dbGetQuery <- DBI::dbGetQuery(dbConnect,dbQuery)
  return(dbGetQuery)
  DBI::dbClearResult(dbGetQuery)
  DBI::dbDisconnect(dbGetQuery)
  lapply(dbListConnections(MySQL()), dbDisconnect)
}
```